# How can I get the SEXPTYPE of an SEXP value?

Tags: c++, rcpp

Suppose I have a function taking an `SEXP` type as a parameter:

```
SEXP myFun(SEXP param)
```

How can I find out the type of this parameter? Looking at the `SEXP` type in my debugger, I can see that I could call `param->sxpinfo.type` to get a numerical representation of the `SEXPTYPE`. From a quick glance, they seem to match with these:

> ```
> no    SEXPTYPE    Description 
> 0 NILSXP  NULL 
> 1 SYMSXP  symbols 
> 2 LISTSXP pairlists 
> 3 CLOSXP  closures 
> 4 ENVSXP  environments 
> 5 PROMSXP promises 
> 6 LANGSXP language objects 
> 7 SPECIALSXP  special functions 
> 8 BUILTINSXP  builtin functions 
> 9 CHARSXP internal character strings 
> 10    LGLSXP  logical vectors 
> 13    INTSXP  integer vectors 
> 14    REALSXP numeric vectors 
> 15    CPLXSXP complex vectors 
> 16    STRSXP  character vectors 
> 17    DOTSXP  dot-dot-dot object 
> 18    ANYSXP  make “any” args work 
> 19    VECSXP  list (generic vector) 
> 20    EXPRSXP expression vector 
> 21    BCODESXP    byte code 
> 22    EXTPTRSXP   external pointer 
> 23    WEAKREFSXP  weak reference 
> 24    RAWSXP  raw vector 
> 25    S4SXP   S4 classes not of simple type
> ```

(source: http://www.biosino.org/R/R-doc/R-ints/SEXPTYPEs.html#SEXPTYPEs)

But this seems hacky. What is the *right* way to check the type of a `SEXP` variable?

Comment: I can scarcely imagine any way to improve on a numeric type. The document you link to seems to imply types are indicated numerically.

Comment: The `TYPEOF` macro is used to get the runtime type of a `SEXP`.

Comment: @Logicrat well I would think a better way would be something like `if (TYPEOF(sexpval) == INSTSXP)` which Kevin seems to suggest might be possible.

Comment: Right, that's the 'idiomatic' way of doing things. With a dynamically typed language like R, you end up writing code like `switch (TYPEOF(x)) { case INTSXP: ... }`, and so on, to handle 'dispatch' on the runtime type.

Comment: @KevinUshey thanks, that was helpful. Feel free to frame your comment as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: This questions, as currently stated, is wrongly tagged as it has nothing to do with C++ or Rcpp; this is plain C and R.  Do you mind if I change that?  [ But if you look eg at the Rcpp Gallery there are Rcpp-based approaches for this too. ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the R API, the `TYPEOF` macro is used to get the runtime type. We can see some relevant bits from `Rinternals.h` (interestingly, *not* encoded as an `enum`, but as a series of macro defines; presumedly for backwards compatibility with some very bad compiler on some very bad platform...)

```
typedef unsigned int SEXPTYPE;

#define NILSXP       0    /* nil = NULL */
#define SYMSXP       1    /* symbols */
#define LISTSXP      2    /* lists of dotted pairs */
#define CLOSXP       3    /* closures */
#define ENVSXP       4    /* environments */
#define PROMSXP      5    /* promises: [un]evaluated closure arguments */
#define LANGSXP      6    /* language constructs (special lists) */
#define SPECIALSXP   7    /* special forms */
#define BUILTINSXP   8    /* builtin non-special forms */
#define CHARSXP      9    /* "scalar" string type (internal only)*/
#define LGLSXP      10    /* logical vectors */
/* 11 and 12 were factors and ordered factors in the 1990s */
#define INTSXP      13    /* integer vectors */
#define REALSXP     14    /* real variables */
#define CPLXSXP     15    /* complex variables */
#define STRSXP      16    /* string vectors */
#define DOTSXP      17    /* dot-dot-dot object */
#define ANYSXP      18    /* make "any" args work.
                 Used in specifying types for symbol
                 registration to mean anything is okay  */
#define VECSXP      19    /* generic vectors */
#define EXPRSXP     20    /* expressions vectors */
#define BCODESXP    21    /* byte code */
#define EXTPTRSXP   22    /* external pointer */
#define WEAKREFSXP  23    /* weak reference */
#define RAWSXP      24    /* raw bytes */
#define S4SXP       25    /* S4, non-vector */

/* used for detecting PROTECT issues in memory.c */
#define NEWSXP      30    /* fresh node creaed in new page */
#define FREESXP     31    /* node released by GC */

#define FUNSXP      99    /* Closure or Builtin or Special */
```

If `USE_RINTERNALS` is defined, we can see that R queries the `SEXPTYPE` with:

```
#define TYPEOF(x)   ((x)->sxpinfo.type)
```

which is exactly as you propsed :) But in most cases (ie -- unless you know what you're doing), you shouldn't be using that `#define`, and so the definition comes from [memory.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/cf97ced7b08483eb671bfcf1a30e329b1b86737b/src/main/memory.c#L3280):

```
int (TYPEOF)(SEXP x) { return TYPEOF(CHK(x)); }
```

...which just makes a call to the `TYPEOF` macro, but uses `CHK` to ensure the `SEXP` it's looking at hasn't already been unprotected.

It is useful to browse the R sources (and definitely take a look at `R.h` and `Rinternals.h`) to get a better idea of what is actually exposed in the R API, and how it is used.

That said, the R API is a bit of an ugly beast, so we really do recommend using `Rcpp`, which provides a number of nice classes that wrap over `SEXP`s but provide compile-time types and a slew of useful functions to using / manipulating them. See @eddelbuettel's [Rcpp page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) for an introduction, and [the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/) for example Rcpp use.

Comment: +1 just for the exquisite Canadian politeness when you say "a bit of an ugly beast"  ;-)