Automatically adapting to arma::mat or arma::sp_mat in an Rcpp::List?
I would like to store and operate an array of matrices (or pointers to them), which could be either arma::mat or arma::sp_mat of varying dimensions (passed from R via Rcpp). What would be the easiest way to achieve this? For example, given the extent of shared operations between the two types, perhaps there is already a parent class that arma::mat & arma::sp_mat derive from? That would allow me to derive pointers to the different matrices and populate my array with. Thank you!
Edit: I had thought storing the input list of matrices in an Rcpp::List would suffice. But for any downstream calculations, I would still need to instantiate an appropriate arma::mat or arma::sp_mat for a given index in the list, so it seems to me that simply storing the input matrices in a List won't be sufficient.

Following the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172419/how-can-i-get-the-sexptype-of-an-sexp-value , using TYPEOF(mi) where SEXP mi=ListObject[i] yields 14 and 25 for standard and sparse (dgCMatrix) matrices respectively. Looking at the table linked by Kevin Ushey in that thread, tells me that the former is "real variables", and the latter a generic "S4" object. Unfortunately, still not a solution in that it does not offer a clean check for dense vs sparse matrix type.

It appears the RcppGallery already has the answer, thanks to the author: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dynamic-dispatch-for-sparse-matrices/
